# jQuery traverse down multiple layers deep to set checked value

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, html-table, jquery-traversing

How do I use jQuery to traverse to this element deep in my table?

**#adminreview > thead > tr > th:nth-child(1) > div > div > div.checkbox-container > div:nth-child(1) > input**

and set the input's checked property to false?

I'm using this nice filter/sort jQuery plug in (Excel-like Bootstrap Table Sorting And Filtering Plugin) on my table. On load, I'm trying to only have one of the options checked, Pending, and will run the jQuery to hide the Approved & Denied rows separately.

On load, all statuses are currently checked by default:

[image: On Load dropdown selected]

Goal is to only have Pending checked on load:

[image: desired options selected on load]

Here is my table html. I know this has to do with traversing the DOM and setting the checked value for Select All, Approved, & Denied to false, but I'm not having much luck.

I assume I'd have to edit `div:nth-child(1)` (2) & (3) and use `.prop('checked', false);` Just not sure how to go that deep using jquery.

HTML (I didn't include the entire table on purpose):

```
<table id="adminreview" class="fbody">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="apply-filter no-search">Status
      <div class="dropdown-filter-dropdown">
        <div class="dropdown-filter-content" style="display: none;">
          <div class="dropdown-filter-sort">
            <span class="a-to-z" data-column="0" data-index="0">A to Z</span>
          </div>
          <div class="dropdown-filter-sort">
            <span class="z-to-a" data-column="0" data-index="0">Z to A</span>
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox-container">
            <div class="dropdown-filter-item">
            <input type="checkbox" value="Select All" checked="checked" class="dropdown-filter-menu-item select-all"
            data-column="0" data-index="0" /> Select All</div>
            <div class="dropdown-filter-item">
            <input type="checkbox" value="Approved" checked="checked" class="dropdown-filter-menu-item item" data-column="0"
            data-index="0" /> Approved</div>
            <div class="dropdown-filter-item">
            <input type="checkbox" value="Denied" checked="checked" class="dropdown-filter-menu-item item" data-column="0"
            data-index="0" /> Denied</div>
            <div class="dropdown-filter-item">
            <input type="checkbox" value="Pending" checked="checked" class="dropdown-filter-menu-item item" data-column="0"
            data-index="0" /> Pending</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div></th>          
      <th class="apply-filter">Company
      <div class="dropdown-filter-dropdown">
        <div class="dropdown-filter-content" style="display: none;">
          <div class="dropdown-filter-sort">
            <span class="a-to-z" data-column="1" data-index="1">A to Z</span>
          </div>
          <div class="dropdown-filter-sort">
            <span class="z-to-a" data-column="1" data-index="1">Z to A</span>
          </div>
          <div class="dropdown-filter-search">
            <input type="text" class="dropdown-filter-menu-search form-control" data-column="1" data-index="1"
            placeholder="Search" />
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox-container">
            <div class="dropdown-filter-item">
            <input type="checkbox" value="Select All" checked="checked" class="dropdown-filter-menu-item select-all"
            data-column="1" data-index="1" /> Select All</div>
            <div class="dropdown-filter-item">
            <input type="checkbox" value="ACME Construction Company" checked="checked" class="dropdown-filter-menu-item item"
            data-column="1" data-index="1" /> ACME Construction Company</div>
            <div class="dropdown-filter-item">
            <input type="checkbox" value="Joe&#39;s Concrete" checked="checked" class="dropdown-filter-menu-item item"
            data-column="1" data-index="1" /> Joe&#39;s Concrete</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div></th>
```

There are other columns with the same class that I don't want to touch:
[image: other columns]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please post actual code instead of images

Comment: Ok. I'll format the html and get it up asap (since it's created on the fly I don't have the source readily available).

Answer (score 0):

You've `item` class on every checkbox. So what you can is loop through all the nodes and set `checked` to `false` for all. And then. Set `checked` to `true` for the last one.

Like

```
$('.item').each(function() {
  $( this ).prop('checked', false);
});
$('.item').last().prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: I'm not sure that will work as there are other columns for Company name, Date, etc that also have checked values with item class that I don't want to touch. Won't this uncheck all check boxes? I think I have to reference the data column and then the specific child somehow. I'll add another screenshot showing more of the table GUI.